# Cant see my form button or footer on page

Tags: html, css, forms

I've build a page with a form and for some reason my button for the form and my footer element is not showing up on the page.

I have added a link so you can check out my code. And I know its a HOT MESS! so if you can give me any tips on the css and html please feel free to let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/jeramiewinchell/j6n0w1tj/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You really need to check many things in that code. All the red tags are "incorrect" tags and errors in the structure of the document: crossed tags (`<label><select></label>...</select>`), two closing `</body>`, incorrectly closed tags: `<button type="submit">Save</buttons </div>`... it's really messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Fair point in the edit. I said it was a mess without giving anything positive.

Here are some tips that could improve the HTML (with links for reference):

- You should specify a doctype (e.g.: `<!doctype html>`) instead of having an empty `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.
  http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#doctype-syntax
- It would be nice to have a `<html>` wrapping everything, and a `<head>` wrapping the title and links. I'm not clear if it's technically valid not to have them (the W3C HTML validator will not validate a page without a `<head>` although it will validate without the `<html>`), but it's nice and it will help keep things organized.
- The links should have a type indicating the mime type (in this case `type="text/css"`).
  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp
- Closing empty elements (e.g.: img, link, input) is not mandatory in HTML5, but it is in XHTML. Depending on the doctype that you choose, you should close them accordingly. Using `/>` at the end is valid for both HTML5 and XHTML, so you may want to consider it.
  http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/
- Don't nest `<p>` tags. Paragraphs are block elements that should contain only phrasing content (= not block/paragraph elements). How to fix it: replace `<p class="site_section1">` with a `<div class="site_section1">`.
  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element
- Always close the block tags that you open. For example, you never close the `<p class="site_section1">` (altough as I said in the previous point, you should making it a `<div>`... and then close it). The result in the browser may be unpredictable.
- I mentioned in my comment above (sorry, I don't know the name in English), you should avoid crossed tags/nesting of tags. This is incorrect: `<label>...<select></label>...</select>`, it should be `<label>...</label><select>...</select>`.
- Again, not mandatory but it could be nice to set a `value` attribute in the `<option>` tags. If you don't specify a value, the value sent will be the content inside between the `<option>` tags (that may be what you want in this case).
- Don't forget all the code and to close the tags correctly! Things like this: `<button type="submit">Save</buttons </div>` can have disastrous results (although it looks more of a typo to me).
- Don't close tags twice (e.g.: you have `</body>` twice)

And for the CSS (also with some links for reference):

- Avoid unnecessary styling. E.g.: `border-radius:0px` is unnecessary because 0 is the default value for border-radius (unless you have defined some previous style and you want to overwrite it).
  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp
- Specifying units is required for values different than 0. E.g.: `margin-left:15` is that 15 in px or em?
  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units
- The units are optional when the value is 0. Some people find it more readable and better because it is shorter; I personally like them. Your call, but always:
- Be consistent: if you omit the units for a zero value, do it in all your definitions. It looks awkward to me to see a `padding:0` (without units) next to a `margin:0px`. It will help you read and maintain the code later.
- You could merge many styles together. For example: `.zonelist23`, `.zonelist24`, and `.zonelist25` are the same, you could define one style only (e.g.: `.zonelist_bml30`) or set all of them together: `.zonelist23, .zonelist24, .zonelist25 { ... }`
- Not mandatory, but nice: The font-family tag should have several names as a "fallback" system. That way, if the browser does not support the first font, it will go to the next and so on.
  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp
- Just out of curiosity: did you meant to put in the stylesheet `.header` or is it `header`? I personally try to avoid classes/ids with the same name as a tag to keep the code easier to understand, but that's a personal choice. As far as I know there's nothing against naming a class like a tag.

---

One way of having fun and learning (you may now think that I have a strange way of having fun and learning):

1. Go to the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).
2. Click on the the "validate by direct input" tab.
3. Copy your code in the box.
4. Click on the "Validate" button.
5. View the first error, and read the comments (visit the links for reference).
6. Fix the code according to what you've read.
7. Click on the "Revalidate" button.
8. Repeat steps 5-7 until no errors are found.

(You can do the same with the CSS in the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/))

Comment: **+1**  a lot of perfect tips ;)

Comment: Btw: don't get scared if the W3C HTML Validator shows only one error, you fix it and after revalidating it shows 2 errors. It may be frustrating (and remind you of this http://www.sharenator.com/image/417017/) but it's a nice experience to go little by little

Comment: Thank you Monty82 i'm learning coding on my own. I  knew it was crappy lol but that was my first webpage i had ever built. Please if you have any tips feel free to share in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/j6n0w1tj/1/

I have corrected your code.

Kindly follow the steps mentioned by @monty82, who has given an excellent explanation on how to proceed with your code.

- Wrong html:

  ```
     <label>..<select></Label><option></option></select>
  ```

  Correct html

  ```
     <label>..</label><select><option></option></select>
  ```
- Tags like `<input>,<br>` are self closing tags,close it like `<input
  type="radio"/> and <br/>` not as `</br>`.
- Please make sure whether your opening and closing tags match